# How to get average of a counted column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select count(user_id) 
from photos 
group by user_id ;

4
3
1
2
1
1
12
5
1
4
8
2
1
4
5
2
1
2
1
1
3
5
4
4
5
1
3
5
5
1
1
8
10
2
1
2
4
5
5
3
1
1
5
1
6
5
1
2
2
2
9
4
11
3
2
1
2
3
2
1
3
2



select avg(count(user_id)) 
from photos 
group by user_id;
```

> Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

How to get average of this column

Comment: The average of a count does not make a lot of sense I dont think?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.

Please post your expected output. It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want average number of times user_id is repeated or?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an average over the entire aggregated table?

```sql
SELECT AVG(cnt) AS avg_cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS cnt 
    FROM photos
    GROUP BY user_id
) t;
```

Comment: i have these  2 situations
Q.1 Provide how many times does average user posts on Instagram. Also, provide the total number of photos on Instagram/total number of users
Bots & Fake Accounts: The investors want to know if the platform is crowded with fake and dummy accounts

Q.2Provide data on users (bots) who have liked every single photo on the site (since any normal user would not be able to do this).

Comment: That sounds like a great other question.  But it is not what you asked above.

Comment: I think i am thinking in wrong way, Can you help me to get answer of above questions please

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be it :

```
select sum(column1)/(select count(*) from  photos) from photos ;
```